# lateinit property ViewModelFactory has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm using dagger 2.25.2 and androidx.lifecycle for dependency injection in my android project. But I've got error ViewModelFactory has not been initialized

Here is my code's

```
class PropertyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var propertyViewModelFactory: PropertyViewModelFactory
    lateinit var propertyViewModel: PropertyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.property_activity)

        propertyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, propertyViewModelFactory).get(
        PropertyViewModel::class.java)

        propertyViewModel.loadProperties()
}
```

ViewModelFactory:

```
class PropertyViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val propertyViewModel: PropertyViewModel) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(PropertyViewModel::class.java!!)) {
            return propertyViewModel as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown class name")
    }
}
```

AppModule:

```
@Module
class AppModule(val app: Application){

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication(): Application = app

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providePropertyViewModelFactory(factory: PropertyViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory = factory

}
```

BuildersModule:

```
@Module
abstract class BuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributePropertyActivity(): PropertyActivity
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidInjectionModule::class,BuildersModule::class, AppModule::class))interface PlotComponent {

    fun inject(app: Application)
}
```

Application Class :

```
class PlotApplication : Application(), HasAndroidInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerPlotComponent.builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(this))
            .build().inject(this)
    }
    override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = activityInjector
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I doesn't see where you inject dependency in your activity. The problem may be in this.

Add

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this)
```

in your onCreate

Comment: isn't AndroidSupportInjection for fragment right?
i tried add AndroidInjection.inject(this) on my onCreate
but i've got error 
lateinit property activityInjector has not been initialized

Comment: did you use apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' ?

Comment: yes i did. is it coz im using dagger version 2.25? because in another project I used version 2.13 its worked

Comment: try to switch on this version and check

Comment: you saved my time. that's great!

Comment: Add AndroidEntryPoint